# Remover barra fixa da barra lateral

Tags: jquery

Estou com o seguinte código:

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
//fix lateral filter and gallery on scrolling
    $('.cd-filter-trigger').click(function () {
        (!window.requestAnimationFrame) ? fixGallery() : window.requestAnimationFrame(fixGallery);
    });

    function fixGallery() {
        var offsetTop = $('.cd-main-content').offset().top,
            scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
        ( scrollTop >= offsetTop ) ? $('.cd-main-content').addClass('is-fixed') : $('.cd-main-content').removeClass('is-fixed');
    }
```

Esse código executa a fixação de uma barra na lateral (um filtro), porém, depois que o usuário clica e a barra é fixada, ela deveria continuar fixar apenas na área ('.cd-main-content'), entretanto, ela fica fixa na lateral inteira da página....
Como posso arrumar isso?

Comment: Olá Hitch, tem como postar o HTML e CSS e se possível simular o problema no Trecho de Código do StackOverflow (preferenciamente) ou JSFiddle? Assim você nos ajuda a te ajudar... :)

Comment: Kadu... O código é esse: http://codyhouse.co/demo/content-filter/index.html, preciso resolver o problema acima nesse código...

Comment: Ali é o código do _framework_, certo? Não é o que está com problema? Faz assim, abre o Developer Tools do navegador e verifica se o elemento com a classe `.cd-main-content` está com `position: relative`, pois pelo que eu vi o `.cd-filter` utiliza `position: absolute`, então ele irá pegar a referência `top: 0` e `left: 0` do parente mais próximo que tenha `position: relative`, se nenhum parente tem esse propriedade ele se referenciará no `body`.

Comment: Hitch, use o [botão editar](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/63360/edit) da sua pergunta, para adicionar/alterar informações, não se deve duplicar perguntas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Altere a função `fixGallery` para o seguinte código:

```
function fixGallery() {
   var offsetTop = $('.cd-main-content').offset().top,
   scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
   //( scrollTop >= offsetTop ) ? $('.cd-main-content').addClass('is-fixed') : $('.cd-main-content').removeClass('is-fixed');
}
```

Comment: Kadu, eu não quero a fixagem suma... Eu quero apenas, que o filtrar fique fixo depois que o filtrar é aberto. Pq quando uso a classe fixa nele antes do filtrar abrir, ele fica fixo na página e fica descendo junto do scroll. Eu quero que o botão filtrar, fique fixo somente quando o filtro estiver aberto, e continue fixo quando o filtrar descer, mas quando ele sair do filtrar, ele volta ao normal com a posição absoluta... Sacou?